# What to do with the result of AWS SES SesClient sendEmail() method?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, email, amazon-ses

## Short:

What do I have to do with the result of the `sendEmail()` method of the SES-API from Amazon AWS?

## Long:

I have successfully installed the `"aws/aws-sdk-php": "^3.38"` via composer in a PHP project.

I have successfully sent emails over the formula:

```
$client = new SesClient( $sesParameters );
$result = $client->sendEmail( $emailSesArgs );
```

It works.

I receive a result like this one:

```
Result {#433 ▼
  -data: array:2 [▼
    "MessageId" => "0102015fd3c21fd2-98a104e2-0c3f-4078-90ed-0be3a12ae812-000000"
    "@metadata" => array:4 [▼
      "statusCode" => 200
      "effectiveUri" => "https://email.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"
      "headers" => array:4 [▼
        "x-amzn-requestid" => "e27b7805-cd11-11e7-9d57-cd9600d88c96"
        "content-type" => "text/xml"
        "content-length" => "326"
        "date" => "Sun, 19 Nov 2017 10:10:35 GMT"
      ]
      "transferStats" => array:1 [▼
        "http" => array:1 [▼
          0 => []
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
}
```

## Questions

The questions are...

- What should I do with this result, further than exploring the `200 OK` result in real time?
- What operations can I perform afterwards using this `MessageId`?
- I've observed that if I send an email to an invalid address, this **also** returns `200 OK`. Probably this is more an "acknowledge" that the send-email "request" has been submitted than actually processing of it. Can I use the result to further read the "status" of the deilvey itself via API to discover if the email was successfully delivered?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm save the MessageId for Delivery Logs. So if I would like to track further actions (if email has been read, has been bounced, etc.) I could update its status.

Answer (score 1):

What I do is I track message deliveries, bounces and complaints using the message ID by configuring SNS topics (SES > Domains > example.com > Notifications) that trigger an AWS Lambda function (SNS > Topics > Subscriptions), which in turn stores/updates the delivery status in a DynamoDB table for later query operations.